# Getting Vue warning: There is already an app instance mounted on the host container in vue3 with the option API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have created the module in laravel and I am using the vue3 with the option API call.

Here is my index.blade.php file

```
@section('content')
    <div id="annual-budget-app">
@if
<component-one />
@else
<component-two />
@endif
</div
@endsection
```

Here is my app.js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ComponentOne from './../components/ComponentOne'
import ComponentTwo from './../components/ComponentTwo'

const annualBudgetApp = createApp();
annualBudgetApp.component('component-one', ComponentOne)
annualBudgetApp.component('component-two', ComponentTwo)

annualBudgetApp.mount('#annual-budget-app');
```

Here is my ComponentOne.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ form_data }}
    </div>

</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'ComponentOne',
    data() {
        return {
            form_data: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchRevenue() {
            this.isLoading = true; // show loading message
            axios.get(this.baseUrl + '/api-call')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.form_data, 'response.form_data');
this.form_data = response.form_data;                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.isError = true; // an error occurred
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false; // data loading complete
                });
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.fetchRevenue()
    }
}
</script>
```

form_data is displayed in the console log but not rendered in the template.
Also getting {} empty object in view({{ form_data }})

One more warning getting in the console

[Vue warn]: There is already an app instance mounted on the host container.
If you want to mount another app on the same host container, you need to unmount the previous app by calling `annualBudgetApp.unmount()` first.

I checked I have only one place to use the id is the annualBudgetApp only

I tried to check by changing the id with a different name but not working.

I used this code to resolve this issue

```
// // Unmount the previous app if needed
if (annualBudgetApp) {
     annualBudgetApp.unmount()
 }
```

Displaying the data but getting the console error

Uncaught TypeError: mountedApp.unmount is not a function

Comment: If it's Vue 3, please, don't spam tags. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The error means what it says. If you believe you have only one annualBudgetApp.mount(), this means that the script could be loaded twice